# JQUERY pass variable to .NET MVC

Tags: jquery, .net

I am trying use JQUERY/AJAX to fill in a `<option> tag` I am follow this tutorial [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/29d7e0/jquery-autocomplete-getting-data-from-database-in-Asp-Net/). Below are my two input controls I am working with.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="inp_provider" placeholder="Provider" required class="form-control input-lg" 
    list="provider" />
    <span class="fa fa-user-md fa-lg"></span>
</div>
<datalist id="provider">
    <option value="Dr. Julian Bashir">
    <option value="Dr. Lenard McCoy">
    <option value="Dr. Beverly Crusher">
</datalist>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="inp_patient" placeholder="Patient" required class="form-control input-lg" list="patient" />
    <span class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></span>
</div>
```

here is part of my script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get('getData',function(data) {
            $.each(data,function(index,value){
                $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo("#inp_patient");
            })
        })
    })
    )
</script>
```

When the user selects a provider, I want it to pass an id so that I can get a list of patients. My .net code has a function called `getData(string id)`.
There are two questions:
1. How can I change the patient controller options when the user changes the selection of the provider controller? 
2. How do I pass a variable to the controller??

Comment: 1. That depends entirely on how you supply those options to the UI. `List<string>`? `Html.DropDownList()`? 2. You can send data using the `data` argument of the `$.get` call. See the jquery docs for more information: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: I am leaning towards the HTML.dropdownlist() option